# Redundant cases from Sum

Tags: summation, assumptions, conditional

I am new to Mathematica. I would like to understand why Mathematica returns redundant cases, and whether it is possible to simplify them to the generic case $(n>1)$ that covers everything $(n\ge0)$.

```
Assuming[n>=0 && p>=0 && p<=1,Sum[k*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n,p],k],{k, 0, n}]]
```

It returns

$$
\begin{cases}
np & n>1\\
-\frac{n(1-p)^np}{-1+p} & n=1\\
0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

This is not wrong, but redundant: The $n=1$ case simplifies to $p$ which is covered by the generic case $n>1$ (I also don't understand why Mathematica doesn't substitute and simplify it, but that's for another question ...). The $\rm True$ case which I think should stand for the only remaining possibility $n=0$, since I added $n\ge0$ assumption, is also covered by the generic case. So I expect to see just $np$ from this calculation given my assumptions...

Can I simplify this somehow? Or should I? If I assign this to a variable and use it in subsequent calculations manipulating with $n$ in the range $n\ge0$, can I expect valid results?

Comment: Apologies everyone, if I take out the backticks from around the LaTeX formula it does not allow me to post it... no idea why. Would appreciate if someone fixed it and let me know what the issue was, thanks

Comment: You can post it as a bitmap (which is OK for output just not desirable for input).  But if you use `FullSimplify` rather than `Assuming`, I think you get what you want:  `FullSimplify[Sum[k*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k], {k, 0, n}], Assumptions -> 0 < p <= 1 && n >= 1]`.  You could also use `Mean[BinomialDistribution[n, p]]` or `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]]` to get `n p`.

Comment: I suspect it is because the answer is constructed in the form `Piecewise[cases]`, which auto-evaluates to `Piecewise[cases, 0]`. E.g. `Piecewise[{{1, x > 2}, {2, x <= 2}}] // InputForm`.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that there is no restriction for `n` to be an integer, positive or negative. Thus this is possible: `Sum[k*PDF[BinomialDistribution[-1, p], k], {k, 0, -1}]`, which gives zero.

Comment: Just add `Simplify`, i.e., `Assuming[n >= 0 && p >= 0 && p <= 1, Sum[k*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k], {k, 0, n}] // Simplify]`

Comment: @JimB Yes, I know it is the mean here but I wanted to post the simplest case. In my concrete problem I needed 3rd and 4th moments but that has the same issue with the redundant cases. Also, if I wrap my code above in either `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` the n=1 and n>1 cases are combined but I still have the 'True' case, so slightly better but still not perfect. I am using Mathematica version 12.1.1.0 on Win11.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I tried just now to `// Simplify` at the end, but it is exactly the same (as expected) as using `Simplify[...]` to wrap the whole thing. It just combines the n=1 and n>1 cases and returns np for n>=1, but that annoying 'True' branch is there.... Also, can I select a branch from here with e.g. an index, like one can for `ConditionalExpression`?

Comment: If you need 3rd and 4th moments, then `Expectation` and `Moment` should be helpful: `Moment[BinomialDistribution[n, p], 3]` results in `n p - 3 (1 - n) n p^2 + (1 - n) (2 - n) n p^3`.  But if your need has to do with something more complex than a binomial distribution, giving a more desired example would be helpful to us.

Comment: @JimB `Moment` is nice, I should have tried. And you don't even need assumptions. Thanks vm!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
PiecewiseExpand[
 Assuming[n >= 0 && p >= 0 && p <= 1, 
  Sum[k*PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], k], {k, 0, n}]],
 n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

[image]